# Json_decode wrongly thinks string of numbers is json

Tags: php, json

My scripts tests to see if an array element contains json.  All works well until I get to the array element which contains a string composed of numbers (zip code).  This is what happens:

```
$s = '70115';
if (json_decode($s)){  
    echo 'this is json';
} else {
    echo 'this is not json';
}
//result: 'this is json'   
//expected result: 'this is not json'
```

I tried explicitly casting $s as a string and encoding it UTF8, but no luck.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: AFAIK this is valid json.

Comment: Then I must be missing something about json.  So any collection of numbers is valid json, but if I put in alpha characters (say $s = 'Chicago';), it's not?

Comment: A string by itself is valid json too. See the site @u_mulder linked, it has good explanation.

Comment: Interesting, but 'Chicago' is not valid json according to json_decode.

Comment: To summarize: a string by itself is a valid JSON *value* when wrapped in double quotes. A number by itself is also a valid JSON value and should not be wrapped in double quotes. So `1.5` and `"Chicago"` are valid JSON values. The latter would look like `'"Chicago"'` or `"\"Chicago\""` as a PHP string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid JSON.

You may want to check if you got an object actually:

```
$s = '70115';

if (is_object(json_decode($s))){  
    echo 'this is json';
} else {
    echo 'this is not json';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [JSON text is defined to be either a serialized object or array](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2):

> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>   JSON-text = object / array
> ```

However, [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) does also decode any other [valid JSON value](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.1).